# Clicking on Big View Notification doesn't launch activity

Tags: android, android-notifications

Clicking on the notification doesn't launch any activity. I followed the developers code but something isn't working. Any suggestions?

```
    Intent dismissIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity1.class);
    dismissIntent.setAction("action1");
    PendingIntent piDismiss = PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 0, dismissIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity2.class);
    notifyIntent.setAction("action2");
    PendingIntent piNotify = PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("Alert")
                    .setContentText("Alert text")
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText("Big text message"))
                    .addAction(R.drawable.icon1,
                            "Dismiss", piDismiss)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.icon2,
                            "Notify", piNotify);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

I also added `android:exported="true"` to the activity in the Manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are calling

```
PendingIntent.getService()
```

instead of

```
PendingIntent.getActivity()
```

as the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) say:

**PendingIntent.getService** :
Retrieve a PendingIntent that will start a **service**, like calling Context.startService(). The start arguments given to the service will come from the extras of the Intent.

**PendingIntent getActivity** : Retrieve a PendingIntent that will start a new **activity**, like calling Context.startActivity(Intent). Note that the activity will be started outside of the context of an existing activity, so you must use the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK launch flag in the Intent.

Comment: Yup. Just figured it out. Thanks